# Kubernetes postStart lifecycle hook exited with 7

Tags: bash, kubernetes, hook, lifecycle

I have a simple bash script to execute at postStart, but i get an error which is not informative at all:

`Exec lifecycle hook ([/bin/bash -c sleep 30;/xcom/scripts/sidecar_postStart.sh]) for Container "perfcibuddy" in Pod "xcomapp-597fb859c5-6r4g2_ns(412852d1-5eea-11ea-b641-0a31ddb9a71e)" failed - error: command '/bin/bash -c sleep 120;/xcom/scripts/sidecar_postStart.sh' exited with 7: , message: ""`

The sleep is there because I got a tip that there might be a race condition, that the script is not in place at the time Kubernetes calls it.

And if I log into the container I can execute the script from the shell without any problem.

The script is just doing a simple curl call (IP obviously sanitized):

```
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Script to perform postStart lifecycle hook triggered actions in container
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

# -------------------------------------------[ get token from Kiam server ]---
role_name=$( curl -s http://1.1.1.1/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/ )
curl -s http://1.1.1.1/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/${role_name}
```

I tried numerous form to set the command in the template (everything in quotes, with && instead of ;), this is the current one:

```
      exec:
        command: [/bin/bash, -c, "sleep 120;/xcom/scripts/sidecar_postStart.sh"]
```

What could be the problem here?

Comment: You didn’t need to sanitize the IP, it’s the AWS metadata server IP or that won’t work ;)

Answer (score 2):

Curl exit code 7 is generally “unable to connect” so your IP is probably wrong or the kiam agent is not set up correctly.

Comment: As i wrote, i can execute the script from container shell without any issue. But at least now i know that the error code is not from Kubernetes. :) Could it be any underlying mechanics of the lifecycle hook handling of Kubernetes?

Comment: Plausible, the kiam agent system is deep dark magic. Can you maybe move your logic from a postStart to an initContainer?

Comment: This container is not the app container, but rather a "sidecar" one, providing additional features which otherwise would require modification of the standardized app image. Also there is a preStop script which needs the credentials. But looking at the template, the role assume is done on deployment level, so i presume the credentials requested in init container will be available in all the containers? Sounds like a plan. :)